# How to install kubernetes / ingress-nginx using kubectl ? (not helm)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I would like to use kubernetes/ingress-nginx using `kubectl apply -f` when I deploy in AKS (Azure), but I cannot figure out how.

I know that I can do `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

but the problem is that this provides a very non-configurable version with a lot of items on it.

Any idea? I don't want to start to edit and customize `deploy.yaml` in the current form as it's super ugly. It is an option but anyone has any better idea?

I know that I can use help, and that's a current production version, but for some reason, I need to try to move to `kubectl apply -f`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use helm template, then kubectl apply on the result? Would this be ok for your use case?

Comment: I thought about that but one of the requirements is not to use helm. I will need to go back and re-discuss that; but meanwhile anyone knows a solution, it would help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Kustomize

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/29/introducing-kustomize-template-free-configuration-customization-for-kubernetes/

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/helloWorld

it was made exactly for your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately in the ops use case he specifically points to https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml this resource cannot be deployed by kustomize due to it containing jobs. This is mentioned in the kustomize.yaml at that location

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using helm3 for installing packages (which allows configuration with maintability as main aim). You can see helm package for nginx-ingress (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) and configure the parameters also.

Note there are multiple version of helm for nginx-ingress. You can choose which works for you the best (one if community maintained and other is nginx maintained).

Edit: - helm template can be used to spit out yaml file which can be used with kubectl to apply directly. Moreover helm3 can directly work with kubectl without any server side component.